# Query to get count of distinct items in groupings

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a table that stores **created** grouping for items from another table like this:

table1
[image: table1]

table2
[image: table2]

So giving the above, I want to write a query that returns the count of items from table1 that a grouping has been created for.

It may sound like doing the below but that is actually not what I'm looking for because the groups have to be manually created for them to appear in table 2 so you may have an item from table1 that does't exist in table 2 because the grouping hasn't been created (i.e id: 555).

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM table1
WHERE group IS NOT NULL
```

The above will return 4 but I need something that looks at table2 and returns 3 which is count of items from table1 whose group exists in the category column of table2.

My real table for this can be pretty large up to 100k+ rows so I don't think it is efficient to check if group string from table1 it exists in table2 one by one as that would probably take forever to run - or is that the only viable solution?

PS: tried to use table markdown but I must have screwed up somehow
PPS categories column is not of json type, its just string

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `table2` would not contain any groups in the array that are not there in `table1`, you can try the following:

```
WITH table1(id, "group", qty) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (111, 'cups', 1),
                 (222, 'plates', 2),
                 (333, 'spoons', 5),
                 (444, null, 2),
                 (555, 'knives', 2))
),
     table2(group_id, categories, count_inventory) as (
         SELECT *
         FROM (VALUES ('A1', CAST(MAP(ARRAY['x'], ARRAY[ARRAY['cups', 'plates']]) AS JSON), 3),
                      ('B1', CAST(MAP(ARRAY['x'], ARRAY[ARRAY['cups']]) AS JSON), 1),
                      ('C1', CAST(MAP(ARRAY['x'], ARRAY[ARRAY['cups', 'spoons']]) AS JSON), 6),
                      ('C4', CAST(MAP(ARRAY['x'], ARRAY[ARRAY['spoons']]) AS JSON), 5)
              ))
SELECT reduce(
    array_agg(CAST(json_extract(categories, '$.x') AS ARRAY(VARCHAR))),
    array[],
    (s, x) -> array_union(s, x),
    x -> cardinality(x)
    )
FROM table2 WHERE categories is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this will be faster but you can prepare an existing categories aggregate. Something like that (also you can try `set_union` instead of `array_agg` with `flatten` and `array_distinct`):

```
SELECT array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(CAST(JSON_EXTRACT(categories, '$.x') as ARRAY(VARCHAR)))))
FROM table2
```

And check that `group` is in the result.